# Making a post request in golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to automate following using golang

- <strike>generate password</strike> (done)
- <strike>push notification to all devices</strike> (done using pushbullet)
- change wifi router password at 192.168.0.1 (needs to be done)

Wifi Router page at 192.168.0.1
[Wifi Router page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I88Tl.jpg)

Here is a raw data captured using *Fiddler*. (When manually changed)

```
POST http://192.168.0.1/goform/form2WlanBasicSetup.cgi HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://192.168.0.1/d_wlan_basic.asp
Cookie: curShow=
X-Skyzip-Mode: high
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 233

domain=1&hiddenSSID=0&ssid=Home&band=9&chan=0&chanwid=1&txRate=0&method_cur=0&method=6&authType=2&length=1&format=1&defaultTxKeyId=1&key1=&pskFormat=0&pskValue=3ADI0NSXEAYOI0M&checkWPS2=1&save=Apply&basicrates=496&operrates=4080
```

and my *golang* code as follows

```
func RouterPass(pass string) {
    routerUrl := "http://192.168.0.1"
    resource := "/goform/form2WlanBasicSetup.cgi"
    data := url.Values{}
    data.Set("domain", "1")
    data.Add("ssid", "Home")
    data.Add("band", "9")
    data.Add("chan", "0")
    data.Add("chanwid", "1")
    data.Add("txRate", "0")
    data.Add("method_cur", "0")
    data.Add("method", "6")
    data.Add("authType", "2")
    data.Add("length", "1")
    data.Add("format", "1")
    data.Add("defaultTxKeyId", "1")
    data.Add("pskFormat", "0")
    data.Add("pskValue", pass)
    data.Add("checkWPS2", "1")
    data.Add("save", "Apply")
    data.Add("basicrates", "496")
    data.Add("operrates", "4080")

    u, _ := url.ParseRequestURI(routerUrl)
    u.Path = resource
    u.RawQuery = data.Encode()
    urlStr := fmt.Sprintf("%v", u) 

    client := &http.Client{}
    r, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", urlStr, nil)
    // r.Header.Add("Authorization", "auth_token=\"XXXXXXX\"")
    r.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    r.Header.Add("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(len(data.Encode())))

    resp, _ := client.Do(r)
    fmt.Println(pass)
    fmt.Println(resp.Status)
}
```

But I'm not able to change password.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no variable named `pass` in scope at the time you call `fmt.Println(pass)`. Not sure about this but my guess would be that is part of the response body, you'll have to unpackage it in order to print that data. For example, if the body is json, use the `encoding/json` package to deserialize into some object or map and then you could do `myType.Password` but you can't just print `pass` magically without extracting it from the response. I would guess everything else is working fine. Most of it looks pretty standard. Comment out that line and check your status.

Comment: password is generated and passed to RouterPass() like ```func main() {
 var password = "NRTW-16SM-QFF2-282L"
 RouterPass(password)
}```

Comment: why not capture again with the go program client, and compare it to the previous capture. and also the response.

Comment: OK, I'm able to change password now but with `form` instead of `data`.

Comment: Please someone tell me how to close this question or mark it as solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully, this will help others.

Code that worked

```
func ChangePassword(password string) {
    hc := http.Client{}
    routerURL := "http://192.168.0.1/goform/form2WlanBasicSetup.cgi"
    form := url.Values{}
    form.Add("domain", "1")
    form.Add("hiddenSSID", "0")
    form.Add("ssid", "Linux-PC")
    form.Add("band", "9")
    form.Add("chan", "0")
    form.Add("chanwid", "1")
    form.Add("txRate", "0")
    form.Add("method_cur", "0")
    form.Add("method", "6")
    form.Add("authType", "2")
    form.Add("length", "1")
    form.Add("format", "1")
    form.Add("defaultTxKeyId", "1")
    form.Add("key1", "")
    form.Add("pskFormat", "0")
    form.Add("pskValue", password)
    form.Add("checkWPS2", "1")
    form.Add("save", "Apply")
    form.Add("basicrates", "496")
    form.Add("operrates", "4080")
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", routerURL, strings.NewReader(form.Encode()))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    req.PostForm = form
    req.Header.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0")
    req.Header.Add("Referer", "http://192.168.0.1/d_wlan_basic.asp")
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    fmt.Println(form)
    resp, err := hc.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(resp.Status)
    fmt.Println(password)
}
```